# Get Box token without user interaction

Tags: box, boxapiv2

I have a C# application where I need to connect to Box and retrieve files automatically without user interaction.  I have a client id and a secret id but now sure how I get the authentication code.  How do I make the OAuth call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible using V2. Try out the new Box platform.